# Windows Authentication for intranet site through Smart TV browsers - ASP.NET MVC (or Active Directory settings)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication, smart-tv

We have an intranet site which has a few pages that display information for Smart TVs around the building. This intranet site uses Windows Authentication to log in the user in or prompt for a login. It basically uses the ASP.NET MVC default setup for Windows Authentication. There is a custom principal, but it really only gives a couple more extensions to the `User` class.

These "Smart TVs" are not so smart.

We cannot navigate to the intranet site through the DNS name: `http://intranetsite/` (they want to Google it... I'm guessing they think it's a Google search or don't understand the DNS response) and navigating by IP address prompts for a password. Most of the TVs freak out if you try to log in or they lose the Windows login credentials after a while and re-prompt (it's very difficult to type with a TV remote control).

[image]

We're to the point of getting a bunch of PC's on a stick to fix this issue (so they can run Windows 10), but I'm throwing a shot in the dark to see if anyone else has worked through this issue.

Either some settings in Active Directory (giving it an alias or user?) that can fix this or a change to how the ASP.NET MVC site works.

One major problem is the navigating by IP. When we go through hostname on a normal PC browser, it automatically authenticates.  When going through IP on a normal PC browser, it asks for credentials even though the user is logged into a Windows PC on the domain.  I'm guessing that's because going by IP directly doesn't talk to the DNS server and therefore doesn't authenticate the user automatically.  I believe fact that the Smart TVs don't want to resolve the hostname `http://testintranet` (or doesn't understand the DNS response), is a problem.

Hopefully someone can think of a workaround. For just the TVs, I can obviously copy my code to a project that doesn't use Windows Auth or we can get PC's hooked up to these TVs, but that doesn't seem like the elegant solution.

Also, we've tried this on many different ages and brands of Smart TVs with similar results.